# How to Retrieve TextArea value from previous page In JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I want to retrieve textarea data from this view.jsp

```
<form action="${addStudentUrl}" method="post"> 
Name:<input name="name" type="text" />
<br> 
<br> 
Email:<input name="email" type="text" />
<br> 
<br> 
Gender:
<br> 
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="1">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="2">Female
<br> 
Description: <textarea id="description"> Enter text here...</textarea>
String description = $("description").val();
<input type="submit" value="Add"/>  
</form>
```

To here TestPackage.java

```
 @ProcessAction(name="addStudent")  
     public void addStudent(ActionRequest actionRequest,  ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException, PortalException, com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException
     {  

         String name=ParamUtil.get(actionRequest, "name", StringPool.BLANK);
         int gender=Integer.parseInt(ParamUtil.get(actionRequest, "gender", StringPool.BLANK)); 
         String email=ParamUtil.get(actionRequest, "email", StringPool.BLANK); 
         String description = ParamUtil.get(actionRequest, "descriptionHidden", StringPool.BLANK);
         StudentLocalServiceUtil.addStudent(name, gender, email, description);
     }
```

I could do it for gender , email and name. Apparently textArea is from a different datatype.

Comment: When the id is `description`, why are you trying to retrieve the value back as `descriptionHidden` ?

Comment: Why do you not set a name="description" in the form and then use it the same way as the other fields ?

Comment: I give it a try. I am still a beginner in programming. Sorry for making this few stupid mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view.jsp you should change the description-element to this:

```
Description: <textarea name="description"> Enter text here...</textarea>
```

Also in your view.jsp you should remove this line:

```
String description = $("description").val();
```

You're using some jQuery here but it is in the middle of your html for some reason. Also if you want to select an element using its id-attribute you should use the selector $("#description").

In your TestPackage.java change the line where you set your description to this:

```
String description = ParamUtil.get(actionRequest, "description", StringPool.BLANK);
```

Comment: THANKS I tried this turns out I was doing the right thing Just that my database for description was varchar 75 too short .

Answer (score 0):

When the id is `description`, why are you trying to retrieve the value back as `descriptionHidden` ?
try

```
String description = ParamUtil.get(actionRequest, "description", StringPool.BLANK);
```

Answer (score 0):

using : `textarea name="description"`